# Duplicating Point Layer for Simulation

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js, turfjs

I'm trying to simulate city traffic movements (at the moment I'm only into vehicles) but I'm having a problem.

What happens is that I'm trying to simulate 1 car per point at the map, but I don't know how to duplicate a certain layer (and each one has a different route), for example this one:

```
map.addSource('point', {
    "type": "geojson",
    "data": pointOnCircle(0)
});

map.addLayer({
    "id": "point",
    "source": "point",
    "type": "circle",
    "paint": {
        "circle-radius": 10,
        "circle-color": "#007cbf"
    }
});
```

I don't know if I could just loop and generate N points with different names or do it in another way.

Here's a video of what I've done until now (for simulating it I created 2 different layers because I didn't know how to duplicate them) :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWZD9aBUFlg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put all your points in the one data layer:

```
map.addSource('points', {
    "type": "geojson",
    "data": pointsOnCircle(0) // change this function to return multiple features
});

map.addLayer({
    "id": "points",
    "source": "points",
    "type": "circle",
    "paint": {
        "circle-radius": 10,
        "circle-color": "#007cbf" // possibly make this a data-driven function
    }
});
```

Your GeoJSON data source would look like:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          146.25,
          -37.16031654673676
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          138.515625,
          35.460669951495305
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -81.5625,
          33.43144133557529
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. Do I have an array of points to treat them separately or how is it treated?(Could you give me an example?) Thanks for your answer!

Comment: When you refer to add your GeoJSON data source, you mean to create antoher file and do something similar to this?  map.addSource('points', {
    "type": "geojson",
    "data": filegeojson
});